# How to reset a single index in Pandas Multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame built from multiple dataframes and I need to reset the first index. I don't want to change anything but the first index; the entire structure and order of everything else should be preserved.

What I currently have is something like this:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('0', 'Albert'),
                                   ('0', 'Isaac'),
                                   ('0', "Charles"),
                                   ('1', 'James'),
                                   ('1', 'Paul'),
                                   ('0', 'Wolfgang'),
                                   ('0', 'Enrico'),
                                   ('0', "John"),
                                   ('1', 'Marie'),
                                   ('1', 'Carol'),
                                   ('2', "Solomon"),
                                   ("2", "Joseph"),
                                   ("2", "Phil"),
                                   ('2', 'Danielle')],
                                  names=['class', 'name'])
columns = ('High', 'Average')
df = pd.DataFrame([(98.8, 97.9),
                   (100.0, 99.9),
                   (76.5, 64.2),
                   (99.3, 98.9),
                   (87.2, 83.3),
                   (98.8, 96.5),
                   (100.0, 97.7),
                   (88.6, 64.2),
                   (99.3, 78.3),
                   (87.2, 81.0),
                   (78.8, 65.9),
                   (99.0, 95.4),
                   (86.1, 74.7),
                   (97.9, 91.1)],
                  index=index,
                  columns=columns)
```

This gives a dataframe that looks like:

```
                 High  Average
class name                    
0     Albert     98.8     97.9
      Isaac     100.0     99.9
      Charles    76.5     64.2
1     James      99.3     98.9
      Paul       87.2     83.3
0     Wolfgang   98.8     96.5
      Enrico    100.0     97.7
      John       88.6     64.2
1     Marie      99.3     78.3
      Carol      87.2     81.0
2     Solomon    78.8     65.9
      Joseph     99.0     95.4
      Phil       86.1     74.7
      Danielle   97.9     91.1
```

I want to reset the "class" index only to start at 0 and iterate to the last entry in "class." The end result should look like this:

```
                 High  Average
class name                    
0     Albert     98.8     97.9
      Isaac     100.0     99.9
      Charles    76.5     64.2
1     James      99.3     98.9
      Paul       87.2     83.3
2     Wolfgang   98.8     96.5
      Enrico    100.0     97.7
      John       88.6     64.2
3     Marie      99.3     78.3
      Carol      87.2     81.0
4     Solomon    78.8     65.9
      Joseph     99.0     95.4
      Phil       86.1     74.7
      Danielle   97.9     91.1
```

I can't figure out how to do this; I've tried using reindex, set_levels; a few other things. I feel like this should be a simple thing to do, so I must be missing something in the options in a built in function (which would be my preferred method, but even something "hacky" at this point would suffice!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new index from your first index level, then merge with the second and set it as new one:

```
import numpy as np

idx = df.index.get_level_values('class')
new_idx = pd.Index((idx != np.roll(idx, 1)).cumsum() -1, name='class')

df = df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                      [new_idx, df.index.get_level_values('name')]))
```

```
>>> df
                 High  Average
class name                    
0     Albert     98.8     97.9
      Isaac     100.0     99.9
      Charles    76.5     64.2
1     James      99.3     98.9
      Paul       87.2     83.3
2     Wolfgang   98.8     96.5
      Enrico    100.0     97.7
      John       88.6     64.2
3     Marie      99.3     78.3
      Carol      87.2     81.0
4     Solomon    78.8     65.9
      Joseph     99.0     95.4
      Phil       86.1     74.7
      Danielle   97.9     91.1
```

*Solution improved by @It_is_Chris*

**Details:**

```
>>> idx.tolist()
['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2']

>>> np.roll(idx, 1).tolist()
['2', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2']
```

Now compare each element of two lists: `'0' != '2'`, `'0' != '0'` until `'2' != '2'`. You have a boolean mask

```
>>> (idx != np.roll(idx, 1)).tolist()
[True, False, False, True, False, True, False,
 False, True, False, True, False, False, False]
```

Apply a cumulative sum minus one on this boolean mask to get your new index:

```
>>> ((idx != np.roll(idx, 1)).cumsum() - 1).tolist()
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Now rebuild your index with the new index and the second level:

```
>>> pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([new_idx, df.index.get_level_values('name')])
MultiIndex([(0,   'Albert'),
            (0,    'Isaac'),
            (0,  'Charles'),
            (1,    'James'),
            (1,     'Paul'),
            (2, 'Wolfgang'),
            (2,   'Enrico'),
            (2,     'John'),
            (3,    'Marie'),
            (3,    'Carol'),
            (4,  'Solomon'),
            (4,   'Joseph'),
            (4,     'Phil'),
            (4, 'Danielle')],
           names=['class', 'name'])
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the loop try: `new_idx = (idx != np.roll(idx, 1)).cumsum() -1`

Comment: @It_is_Chris. Thanks for this improvement. I updated my solution.

Comment: This works great! Could you explain a little of what's going on here? I see that it works, but I'm not 100% on how it works. (Answer accepted, though, as this solution is exactly what I needed.)

Comment: I updated my answer. I tried to give you more details. Is that clear enough?

Comment: That clears up the methodology quite nicely; thanks, @Corralien, for your thorough and very useful answer! I learned something today.

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
df = df1.reset_index()
df['class'] = df['class'].astype(int).diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum().astype(int)
df = df.set_index(['class', 'name'])
>>> df
                index   High  Average
class name                           
0     Albert        0   98.8     97.9
      Isaac         1  100.0     99.9
      Charles       2   76.5     64.2
1     James         3   99.3     98.9
      Paul          4   87.2     83.3
2     Wolfgang      5   98.8     96.5
      Enrico        6  100.0     97.7
      John          7   88.6     64.2
3     Marie         8   99.3     78.3
      Carol         9   87.2     81.0
4     Solomon      10   78.8     65.9
      Joseph       11   99.0     95.4
      Phil         12   86.1     74.7
      Danielle     13   97.9     91.1
```

This also does not work with the index, so it is set before and after some changes in the `class` column.

**Comment**

In my first attempt I used this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['class'] = df['class'].astype(int).diff().abs().cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int)
df = df.set_index(['class', 'name'])
```

This will generate the correct results for the given example, because the difference in the "class"-column is only `-1` or `1`.If the difference is different from `-1`, `0` or `1`, this would genreate wrong results.

Comment: df.reset_index() takes away all of the structure and just iterates everything on the "name" index.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment, but I did run my code again and edited the output.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to reset index then create the groups out of it then reindex back

```py
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2['class'] = (df2['class'] != df2['class'].shift()).cumsum() - 1
df = df2.set_index(['class', 'name'])
>>>
                 High  Average
class name
0     Albert     98.8     97.9
      Isaac     100.0     99.9
      Charles    76.5     64.2
1     James      99.3     98.9
      Paul       87.2     83.3
2     Wolfgang   98.8     96.5
      Enrico    100.0     97.7
      John       88.6     64.2
3     Marie      99.3     78.3
      Carol      87.2     81.0
4     Solomon    78.8     65.9
      Joseph     99.0     95.4
      Phil       86.1     74.7
      Danielle   97.9     91.1
```